# ¿Cómo redirigir de acuerdo al tipo de usuario que inicia sesión?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando con PHP, framework Codeignter 3.

Tengo dos tipos de usuarios, el administrador y el usuario cliente. Dentro de la tabla usuario tengo el atributo tipo_usuario_id donde 1 es admin y 2 es cliente.

Voy a ir siguiendo todos los pasos del login. Empiezo con la vista, donde tengo el formulario para poner DNI y CONTRASEÑA:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Welcome/login" id="formulario-login-usuario">
    <!--<img class="mb-4" src="" alt="" width="72" height="57"> -->
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Iniciar Sesión</h1>

    <div class="form-floating">
      <input name="dni" type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="38928298">
      <label for="floatingInput">DNI</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input name="clave" type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Contraseña">
      <label for="floatingPassword">Contraseña</label>
    </div>

    <!--<div class="checkbox mb-3">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div> -->
    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="btn-login">Entrar</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2021</p>
  </form>
```

Luego tengo este AJAX, donde pensaba ver si trae 1 o 2 y, dependiendo de ese valor, redirigir a la vista correspondiente:

```
//login de administradores o usuarios
$(document).on('submit', '#formulario-login-usuario', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var action = $(this).attr('action');
  var method = $(this).attr('method');
  var data = new FormData(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: action,
    type: method,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#btn-login').attr('disabled', true);
      $('#btn-login').text('Verificando...');
    },
    success: function(resp) {
      if (!resp.success) {
        swal({
          title: 'Error',
          text: resp.message,
          type: 'error'
        });

        $('#btn-login').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#btn-login').text('Entrar');
      } else {
        console.log(resp); //ACA ME TRAE TRUE. 
        console.log(data); //ACA ME TRAE EL FORM.
          //window.location.href = base_url + 'ADMINISRTADOR';
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      swal({
        title: 'Error',
        text: xhr.responseText,
        type: 'error'
      });
      $('#btn-login').attr('disabled', false);
      $('#btn-login').text('Entrar');
    }
  });
});
```

El action del form es el controlador:

```
public function login() {
        $errores = array();
        $mensaje = null;
        $dni = trim($this->input->post('dni'));
        $clave = trim($this->input->post('clave'));
        $claveEncriptada = crypt($clave, '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');
        $verificarDatos = $this->Usuario->login($dni, $claveEncriptada);
        if (empty($dni)) {
            $errores[] = 'Debes ingresar tu DNI';
        }
        if (empty($clave)) {
            $errores[] = 'Debes ingresar tu contraseña';
        }
        if (!$verificarDatos) {
            $errores[] = 'Datos incorrectos, intente nuevamente';
        }

        if (count($errores) <= 0) {

            $datos['session'] = array(
                'id_session' => $verificarDatos->id_usuario,
                'nombre' => $verificarDatos->nombre,
                'apellido' => $verificarDatos->apellido,
                'celular' => $verificarDatos->celular,
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($datos);

            $mensaje = array(
                'success' => true
            );

        } else {
            foreach (array_reverse($errores) as $key => $error) {
                $err = $error;
            }

            echo $err;
        }

        if ($mensaje) {
            echo json_encode($mensaje);
        }
    }
```

Mi pregunta es, donde hacer correctamente el redireccioanmiento. Yo pensaba hacerlo en el AJAX, ya que ahí tengo la funcion **window.location.href** pero no se como acceder al atributo de la base de datos correspondiente !! Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: El método `$this->Usuario->login()` debería devolver el tipo de usuario, para agregarlo en las variables de sesión y, además, incluirlo en la respuesta JSON.

Comment: @Triby como lo incluyo en la respuesta JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes asegurarte de que el método `$this->Usuario->login()` devuelve también el tipo de usuario y, después, agregas el dato tanto en sesión como en JSON. También devuelve siempre un JSON válido:

```
public function login() {
    $errores = array();
    // Inicializar arreglo para JSON, por defecto con error
    $mensaje = [
        'success' => false,
        'error' => ''
    ];
    $dni = trim($this->input->post('dni'));
    $clave = trim($this->input->post('clave'));
    $claveEncriptada = crypt($clave, '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');
    $verificarDatos = $this->Usuario->login($dni, $claveEncriptada);
    if (empty($dni)) {
        $errores[] = 'Debes ingresar tu DNI';
    }
    if (empty($clave)) {
        $errores[] = 'Debes ingresar tu contraseña';
    }
    if (!$verificarDatos) {
        $errores[] = 'Datos incorrectos, intente nuevamente';
    }

    if (count($errores) <= 0) {

        $datos['session'] = array(
            'id_session' => $verificarDatos->id_usuario,
            'nombre' => $verificarDatos->nombre,
            'apellido' => $verificarDatos->apellido,
            'celular' => $verificarDatos->celular,
            // Agrega el tipo de usuario en sesión
            'tipo_usuario' => $verificarDatos->tipo_usuario_id
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($datos);
        // Actualiza el arreglo
        $mensaje['success'] = true;
        // Agrega el tipo de usuario
        $mensaje['tipo_usuario'] = $verificarDatos->tipo_usuario_id;
    } else {
        foreach (array_reverse($errores) as $key => $error) {
            $errores = $error;
        }
        // Agrega el error a la salida final
        $mensaje['error'] = $err;
    }
    // Siempre devuelve un objeto JSON
    echo json_encode($mensaje);
}
```

En Javascript solo hay que hacer algunas modificaciones:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: action,
    type: method,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#btn-login').attr('disabled', true);
      $('#btn-login').text('Verificando...');
    },
    success: function(resp) {
      if (!resp.success) {
        swal({
          title: 'Error',
          // Mostrar la propiedad error creada en PHP
          text: resp.error,
          type: 'error'
        });

        $('#btn-login').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#btn-login').text('Entrar');
      } else {
          // Analizar tipo de usuario
          if(resp.tipo_usuario == 1) {
              // Redirigir a página de administrador
          } else {
              // Redirigir a página de cliente
          }
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      swal({
        title: 'Error',
        text: xhr.responseText,
        type: 'error'
      });
      $('#btn-login').attr('disabled', false);
      $('#btn-login').text('Entrar');
    }
  });
});
```

Por último, en cada página de administrador verifica que el tipo de usuario guardado en sesión es correcto.